# Would 'sitting in a queue' be incorrect English?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

Usually, to avoid any ambiguities, I'd say 'waiting in the queue', however I came across 'sitting in a queue' and wanted to know whether it's correct or incorrect English.

Is it used? And if yes, in what context/s?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is, but generally more so in certain contexts. For example, if I'm stuck in traffic I would say "sitting in queue", but I probably wouldn't use the word 'sitting' if I was talking about waiting for a teller at a bank.

Comment: It is, however, uncommon to hear in North America. If I'm stuck in traffic I say "I'm stuck in traffic." or "There is a huge line of traffic."

Comment: @RickHenderson Well in North America, it's uncommon to use the word "queue," but that doesn't seem to be what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @RickHenderson Only because, in North America, "queue" isn't generally used.  People would think you're talking about a pool cue.  North Americans use "line" instead of "queue."  And "sitting in line" or "sitting in a line" are common and correct phrases over here.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Maybe you don't - programmers definitely use it though. ;)

Comment: @Daniel The OP did ask about context, and I stated I was talking about North America while the OP did not indicate their location.

Comment: It should be noted that "sitting in a turnip" is not "incorrect English", even though it is somewhat nonsensical, and certainly not idiomatic.

Answer (score 27):

I'm from the UK and "Sitting in a queue" is a perfectly normal thing to say.

Sometimes the word "sitting" can be used to mean "staying in one place" (like you might sit an object on a table).  In this sense, people might say that they were "sitting in the queue for hours", even if they spent the entire time *standing up*:  "sitting" in this usage means that the queue was moving so slow that they spent extended periods of time not moving at all.  Also, of course, they might mean that they were actually sitting down:  this might refer to the type of queueing system where you take a ticket and sit down and wait for your ticket's number to be called.

The phrase "sitting in a queue" is also often used to describe inanimate objects, or even virtual objects, such as emails, helpdesk tickets etc.  For example:

"Did you deal with that purchase order problem yet?"
"No, it's been sitting in my queue since tuesday"

Comment: *Sit an object on a table*? Really? I haven't heard that usage. Where in the UK are you from? Would this be similar to the (also strange to my ears) _I'm sat here_ to mean _I'm sitting here_?

Comment: I've heard it used like "Where shall i put this box?", "Sit it on the table thanks."  Now that i think about it more, i think it's a misuse of "sit" as a replacement for "set", meaning "place it on the table", but it does appear to be recognised as a valid word, here at least http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sit - see the Thesaurus section.

Comment: @Terdon [edit] I didn't see Max's comment that I would also say but it probably comes about because you say: 
"I set the cup on the table." and "My cup was sitting on the table."

Comment: @RickHenderson some UK regional dialects use _sit_ in odd ways. I mentioned _I'm sat here_ in my previous comment. This is likely another example of that.

Comment: Then of course there's "We were *stood standing* in the queue for hours," which is one of my favorite UK emphasis phrases...

Comment: @terdon - no it's not related to the (horrible) use of 'sat' for 'sitting' - someone who makes that error would say "I was _sat_ in a queue"

Comment: @terdon Have you never heard people invite you to “sit yourself [or indeed ‘your arse’] down”? Same construction.

Comment: As a native speaker of US English, I would say that the inanimate object use sounds perfectly reasonable: "the request is sitting in a queue" is just as valid as "waiting". However, I wouldn't say that *I* was "sitting in a queue for hours" even if the line wasn't moving, unless I, say, brought a chair with me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet not quite. Those are things that are capable of performing the action of sitting. I think what makes it sound odd to me is using it for something that can't. I could sit a doll down on a table but not a bottle, for example.

Comment: @terdon Well, that's an interpretation I haven't heard before. The construction itself is really just using the intransitive _sit_ instead of the transitive _set_ (the opposite of how so many people now use the transitive _lay_ instead of intransitive _lie_ in phrases like “Lay down”); I've never seen anyone make a connection to actual sitting in the buttocks-on-a-surface sense before.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I may be just talking out of mine then. I hadn't made the connection before this answer got me thinking about it either. All I really know is that *sit it down on the table* sounds weird to me while *sit yourself down* doesn't.

Answer (score 8):

It is perfectly correct English.  I do it every morning on the way to work.

The phrase is often used for circumstances such a a queue of traffic.  You are sitting in your car in a queue.

Comment: This is the most common use in my opinion. Whilst the examples in @Max Williams answer wouldn't sound weird to me if I heard them, I don't think I ever have, or would use it myself.

Comment: Good point that *I'm sitting in a queue* can also be a short form of *I am sitting and also in a queue* rather than describing how you are going about the queueing itself.

Answer (score 2):

There are two common types of queue I am often in - people in a line (eg at the bank) and cars on a busy road. Usually, saying that I am in a queue implies that I am (of course) waiting.  So usually I would not say that I am 'waiting' in a queue.

When it is a queue of people -
***I'm in a queue/ I'm queuing*** (waiting is understood). Or, ***I'm in a queue waiting ... (to be served)***. If the queue is moving too slowly you might say ***I've been stood/waiting in this queue for ages***.

When it is a queue of cars - ***I'm in a queue/ I'm queuing*** (waiting is understood). Or, ***I'm in a queue waiting ... (to join the motorway)***. If the queue is moving too slowly you might say ***I've been stuck/sitting in this queue for ages***. (NB In a car I would not ordinarily say that I am 'waiting' in the queue).

Comment: another common type of queue: A telephone system. I would tend to use the phrase "sitting in a queue" for that too, especially if I had to wait a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Sitting in a queue is definitely proper english when used in proper context. however a good look at the definition for "sitting" and "queue" Straight from the Oxford Dictionary is a great idea as some usage may not be suitable nor proper english.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/sitting
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/queue

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's correct. You need not be resting your derrière on a bench or chair to be sitting.

See, for example,

- Meaning #6 at [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sit) (**sit** [*v.*] *to be situated or located*),
- Meaning #2 at [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/sit) (**sit** [*v.*] *to be in a particular situation or condition for a period of time*),
- Meaning #1.9 at [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sit) (**sit** [*v.*] *be or remain in a particular position or state*).

That said, *standing* might be a better word, particularly if you're standing upright, and only in the queue for five minutes or so. But *sitting* is not (to quote your title) "incorrect English."

Answer (score 0):

If, for example, I was waiting to see a doctor -- where there's a queue (even with appointments, since the doctor almost always runs over time) and those waiting in the queue will be actually sitting waiting for their turn, if I was talking to someone on the phone I might say to them "I am sitting in a queue".

But if I was standing in a queue, I wouldn't normally describe that as sitting (I consider it if I was trying to use the word "sit" in a slightly different sense, that of being situated in some place -- but I'd usually tend to avoid it in this context, not least for the hope of avoiding ambiguity).